# Better ways to setup a webserver behind ISP's NAT

Tags: webserver, nat

Our entire road is behind an ISP NAT that I can't access. Our ISP wont forward a port either. My workaround, I setup an ipv4 to ipv6 tunnel using freenet6. I get a domain like mydomain.broker.freenet6.net, that seems to have solved my problem as everyone can just normally enter it in their browser and connect to my server. The problem is freenet6 is not very stable, the tunnel is disconnecting all the time, sometimes lasting for hours.

I need a better and stable solution, so if you know any other ipv6 tunnel company that provides the same free of charge that would be great.

I can't change ISP (all of them uses NAT here)

I don't want to pay for hosting as it defeats the purpose of me running my own server where I can literally do ANYTHING I want. (getting a dedicated server is too expensive, my ISP has enough speed to host a server, same upload and download speed, it's just being behind a NAT that you can't control is making me nuts.)

Comment: have you considered buying public ip address from your ISP? or maybe ask for port forwarding/range forwarding? other than that you can only setup ipv6 - ipv4 tunnel what you already did or setup a middle server. On the middle server you can setup a tunnel if your ISP will allow port forwarding or you can setup VPN network on the middle server and connect to this VPN network from behind the NAT. It will allow tunneling without port forwarding and involving your ISP.

Comment: ISP is not selling public ip in my area, they won't even forward a single port. Actually right now i'm looking for a tunnel broker just like freenet6 but unfortunately since I started searching about 1 month ago I havn't found anyone doing it like freenet6, the closest is sixxs but they need a public ip4 ip to hook onto. I'm beginning to think that the next best thing is like what you have said about a middle server, but for now i'm still searching for another company that provides free ipv6 tunnel like freenet6.

Comment: If the ISP won't work with you to set this up, then I can probably guarantee that running your own web server from their network will be listed as a violation of your terms of service and if they catch it, will likely cause them to terminate your account. Then you'll be left with a server (and a house) that has no connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its for personal use, you could probably use the [pagekite](http://pagekite.net/) and simply run IPV4 over that - its a service that does some kind of tunneling and relaying.

That said I run freenet fairly reliably, with their linux client, and a [nice little upstart script](https://serverfault.com/questions/117584/upstart-scripts-run-a-task-after-networking-goes-up) that works well for me.

Comment: As [Pagekite](http://pagekite.net/) is one of a field of equivalent options, here's a blog post that summarizes all the players (as of 2013) and compares them : [A Survey of the Localhost Proxying Landscape](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/a-survey-of-the-localhost-proxying-landscape)

Answer (score 3):

I think running your own server at home will prove you to be a real PITA if you need some
reliability on the service you provide.
There’s a step before getting a dedicated server that is a VPS (Virtual Private Server)
A VPS is far cheaper than a dedicated server, the hosting company installs the OS you want 
(different Linux flavors), and you get a remote root access to the box being able to do whatever you want.

I’ve used in the past (about a year ago) a VPS from www.intovps.com and I was very happy with them.
(please I’m not related to them at all)